# Getting requesting client's IP address on server

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have a HttpListener where I'm interested in being able to see the IP address of the requesting clients. A bonus would also being able to see the DNS of the client, but I'm not sure how that would be possible since as far as I know that information is not being sent with HTTP?

Anyway, as far as I can see, I should be able to use `Request.UserHostAddress` for this, but I'm just getting my local IP address. What am I doing wrong here?

Where I should get the client IP.

```
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        string clientName = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Where I'm writing out on a server output listbox I have:

```
        public static void TileString(int x, int y, int z, string dbName, string clientName)
        {
        int[] tileInts = { z, x, y };
        string tileString = string.Join("/", tileInts);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
            mainWindow.AppendServerOutput("Delivering tile " + tileString + " in format [z, x, y]" + " from " + dbName + " to client " + clientName + "\n");
        }));
        }
```

Comment: Client DNS name is `context.Request.UserHostName;`. But it looks you have written correct code. Is clientName somewhere overwritten? What is shown when you add `Debug.WriteLine("client is: " + clientName);` after first code fragment (to be sure nothing is overwritten)?

Comment: And what is `context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());` showing?;

Comment: @Sjips Using RemoteEndPoint.ToString() showed me exactly what I wanted. I can't believe I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to use:

```
string clientIP = context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution?

Comment: If behind proxy or ip forwarding, this will be often proxy address, not the client address

Answer (score 4):

From the MSDN documentation for the [`HttpListenerRequest.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets the server IP address and port number to which the request is directed.

In other words, it's not the remote end-point's address. It's the address of the *server* that the remote end-point used.

As you have seen, you can use the `RemoteEndPoint` to retrieve the IP address of the remote end-point.

Use the `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry()` method to do reverse-DNS lookups (i.e. retrieve the remote host name for the IP address).

Comment: When using `RemoteEndPoint` shouldn't I be able to just say `string clientName = Dns.GetHostEntry(clientIp).ToString();
` to get the domain name of clientIp? I just get "No such host is known"

Comment: `IPHostEntry` doesn't override `ToString()`, so presumably you mean something else (e.g. the `HostName` property). But in any case, yes...that will often work. But no, you can't assume it will _always_ work. You have to be dealing with an IP address that the DNS server knows about.